# Subdivision Surface modifier, `adaptive` not available?

Tags: modifiers, displacement

i´m using blender 3.3 and i have the following issue.
In experimental mode there is an `adaptiv` option in the subdivision surface modifier, which is great if you work with texture displacement from the shader nodes. But if you add an displacement modifier after the subdivision surface modifier, the `adaptive´ option seems to be not available anymore.
Can anyone confirm? Or am I missing something?
Greetz

Comment: That's correct. The reason is, the _Adaptive Subdivision_ is dependent from the image resolution and changes with the distance of the object from the camera. The _Displacement_ modifier is a _constructive modifier_ and in order to correctly displace a mesh it needs the geometry to be consistent no matter what image resolution or distance to the camera. To create displacement that changes with the resolution you can only use the _Displacement_ node in the _Shader Editor_.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your quick respose!